# What does "a man lives after his life but not after his Dishonor" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I read a book some days ago and couldn't understand the meaning of this sentence:
"A man lives after his life but not after his dishonour." 
I've searched for the meaning of this sentence several times but didn't get any results. Anyone can tell?
(Just in case if anyone wants to know, the name of the book from where I got this sentence is "Millicent's Gift" written by Ann Rinaldi.)

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that once we depart from this world, only by our *good deeds*, we are remembered. The charity, sympathy, humanitarian works, and our true selflessness will count once we die. This means, *a man lives after his life.*

It' all about an honor, respect, and dignity. If you *lose your identity or honesty,* you lose everything. That said, if you are labeled as *dishonest,* you *actually die and are **not** alive anymore.*

In short, being *dishonored* is worst than death; that shame is terrible than death.

Comment: There are many who are remembered for their bad deeds rather than any virtue.

Comment: I talked keeping *the context in mind!* @RonaldSole